How to make the browser detect the username-field when prompting to store the credentials
We have an username-password based authentication using Flutter web. When we enter username and password, the Browser prompt for saving credentials dialog doesn't fill (or detects) username but it detects password field. Is there any property I can set on TextFormField so username field can be detected for saving in prompt?
Below is our form with TextFormField widget:

Following is Google chrome prompt after sign-in which doesn't fill username:


Can you please add the relevant code inside the question as well? [ask]

The solution provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61952871/1779027 works great.
